# sending phantomjs setting in golang

Tags: selenium, go, phantomjs

I'm using the go selenium package: `https://github.com/tebeka/selenium` and using the phantomjs browser:

```
caps := selenium.Capabilities{
    "browserName": "phantomjs",
}

wd, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I'm trying to also send along some phantomjs settings so I can set the user-agent string. I'm trying to make a crawler and certain websites won't load with a headless browser user-agent. I know this can be done with python and other languages but I haven't seen any examples in go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set driver binary path and browser name:

```
caps := selenium.Capabilities{
    "browserName":           "phantomjs", // "chrome", or any other
    "phantomjs.binary.path": "/path/to/phantomjs", // path to binary from http://phantomjs.org/
}
```

PhantomJS should be installed in your system.